# How to Return cached JSON data through HTTPResponse in Django?

Tags: django, caching, redis, django-rest-framework, httpresponse

Need some advice, sorry if this violates the policy of asking questions.

I am working on a project in Django-rest and have below requirement:

'A' is a Django-rest API which is getting consumed by users.

'B' is separate from 'A' and using some open source APIs it gets data and do some processing on it and save it into Redis cache. The cache gets updated after every 8 hours.

Now, I want a specific API call of 'A', like v1/trending-api, to get that cached data from 'B' and serve to end users.

Problem:

**How do I access cached data(in JSON) of other API setup and serve it as an HTTPResponse?**

Any reference would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your API method 'A' should return data currently available in the Redis cache. 'B' sounds like it would be a separate cronjob to which would fetch data to populate Redis and not be exposed through the django-based REST API. Both have read / write access to the Redis instance correct?

Regarding other APIs, you can always proxy (i.e "user <-> django <-> other-api" all over http)